# In C++11 the signal.h header has no kill function

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, kill-process

I just tried compiling code that I wrote a while ago using Gnu g++ in C++11 mode, to see if the code will need reworking anytime soon (I also plan to test it in C++17 mode for the same reason).

I found that the kill() function caused a compiler error and it seems that the kill function no longer exists in the signal.h header.

I just looked at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/csignal/ as a reference which seems to confirm this is not just a Gnu-specific omission, but seems to be in the standard.

I can't find a rationale for this omission anywhere, nor can I find any proposal for how I should manage processes without it. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why don't you share a [mcve] ?

Comment: kill is a POSIX function, and not part of Standard C++ (or Standard C).

Comment: @Scheff kill works on processes, not threads.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Oops, where did I see threads? My fault. It's time to leave the office...

Answer (score 3):

C++ standard function is [`raise`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/raise).

[`kill`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/kill.html) is a function *required* by POSIX standard.

C++ standard *doesn't require* this function, which means it is outside the scope of C++ standard.

Answer (score -1):

OK, I was too quick to post that question, of course fork/kill etc are not part of the C++ standard in the first place but are common additions on unix-like platforms.

My real problem was that I used the wrong compiler switch. For anyone else hitting this problem, to get strict C++11 standard, use:

```
g++ -std=c++11
```

But to get the C++11 standard plus non-standard extensions use:

```
g++ -std=gnu++11
```

Using the latter, I can build and call fork/kill no problem.

Comment: `kill` function is not a part of C or C++ standards, regardless of the compiler switch. It just so happens that in C++11 mode your compiler ends up including an extra system header declaring `kill` function.